# How to manage old replication issue

Tags: sql-server-2008, replication, transactional-replication, merge-replication

**Background**

We are using `SQL Server 2008` and we had a merg`e replication` configured (before i joined the company). After that they stopped using it and the didn't delete it and configured `transactional replication` over it leaving orphan jobs and a noisy error with the **number 14151** as it keeps showing in my error log.

After a few search I understood that the main cause of this error is the old merge replication and that I had to delete it.

**Problem**

Problem is shown in the snapshot attached. So could you help me please get rid of this noisy error.

[image]

[![enter image description here][3]][3][image]

Comment: The Error 14151 is the Replication:agent failure error. Have you check out your sql server agent. Is it enable there or not.

Comment: sql server agent is working and enabled.

Comment: Just check out the "Alert" underhood of SQL server Agent . There Alert of Replication : Agent Failure is Enable or not. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/repltalk/archive/2010/05/09/all-about-automatically-monitoring-replication-agent-failures.aspx

Comment: the agent failure is not enabled. do i just have to enable it and the problem is solved?

Comment: No . Just it gives to you related to error 14151 "alert" and "Windows Application Event Logs".

Comment: Have you check out from which account you are running SQL server agent. That has proper privilege to run the agent job or not. for ref https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/911305#/en-us/kb/911305

Comment: yes it was the first thing to check and its its the " sa " user which is working